# Vector iteration with multiple conditions?

Tags: c++, vector

Say you have the following vector of Int's:

```
std::vector<int> V={5,4,3,2,1,6,7,8};
```

I need to write some form of iteration that will push all the decreasing int's into a separate vector **as well as** the first increasing int.

So for V, I require {5,4,3,2,1,6}

My initial thought was to use a for-loop:

```
std::vector<int> Results;

for(int i=V.size(); i--;)
{
  if(V[i]>V[i+1]){Results.push_back(V[i]);};
}
```

However its at this point I'm stuck, how can I also push back the first increasing element (in this case 6)?

Comment: Why not copy all the decreasing and then one more after the loop? Also, your current loop makes no sense.

Comment: If you have special edge cases, post them in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your code. For example: break when the stop condition is reached.

```
std::vector<int> results;

for(int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
{
  results.push_back(v[i]);

  if(v[i] < v[i+1])
  {
    results.push_back(v[i+1]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Every time a loop variable needs to be extracted out of a loop in examples like this, I understand once again why python added an `else` clause onto the loop constructs.

Comment: This doesn't provide an adequate answer. What is the vector begins with a first index lower that the second? The loop stops and does not progress.

Comment: @BabraCunningham, did you actually check that before making this assertion? Also, your problem description and example don't demonstrate that it *should*

Comment: Yes - try it yourself... V={1,5,4,3,2,6,8,9} fails

Comment: @BabraCunningham, your post didn't specify it should continue past the first point where the condition doesn't hold. It's not my role to psychicly deduce that.

Comment: I never said you had too, i said your answer wasn't adequate as it doesn't provide a complete solution.

Comment: @BabraCunningham, You know, the fix really is quite simple. But it's obvious you didn't spend a single moment thinking about it before demanding an "adequate" solution. I add it here for posterity.

Comment: @BabraCunningham It's obviously your question which _"isn't sufficient"_ in the 1st place.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's why you should refrain answering _off-topic_ questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool decrease = false;
    for(i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
    {   
        if(V[i] > V[i+1]) {
            decrease = true;
            results.push_back(v[i]);
        } else if(decrease == true) {
            break;
        }   

    }
```

You can add a flag to represent if the decrease sequence started.